# React first displays the ELSE part of a ternary comparison instead of the IF part

Tags: reactjs

While I am filling an array, I am trying to display a loading event. Then I check whether the array contains a content greater than 0. If this is the case, then I would like to map through the array. But if the length of the array is 0, then I would like to display the ELSE part. Now it is the case that while the array is being filled, the ELSE part is displayed briefly and as soon as axios has filled the array, the correct part. But I don't want that. Why is that so? The array is NEVER empty!

```
export default function Main() {

 const [durchläufe, setAlleDurchläufe] = React.useState([]);
 const [lädtDurchläufe, setLädtDurchläufe] = React.useState(false);

 async function ladeAlleDurchlauefe() {

   setLädtDurchläufe(true);

   await axios.get(url + "AlleDurchlaeufe").then(function (resp) {

     setAlleDurchläufe(resp.data);

      setLädtDurchläufe(false);
  });
}

React.useEffect(() => {
 //HERE I WANT TO FILL THE ARRAY
  ladeAlleDurchlauefe();
 }, []);

return (

 <>
  <Container style={{ marginTop: "35px", marginBottom: "25px" }}>
    <Row className="justify-content-center">

    //Here the ELSE statement is called first
      {durchläufe.length > 0 ? (
        durchläufe.map((durchlauf, index) => {

          return (<h1>OK</h1>);
        })) : (

        <>
         <h1>Some other Code </h1>
        </>
      )}

    </Row>
  </Container>
 
 </>);

}
```

Comment: As `ladeAlleDurchlauefe` is an async call, Initially the array length will be zero and It will load your else part before getting the data

Comment: The initial state is an empty array `[]`, so the length is 0 so the false branch is returned/rendered. What are you expecting on the initial render? If you want neither to render initially then you should use a "loading" state and return null until the data fetching is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Hi the array is empty as you are not awaiting the function call in the useEffect. Your use effect is called on component mount which then calls the api, but doesn't await the response so the component is rendered with no data.

Usually what I do is set loading to true when I call the api so that I can show a loading spinner whilst I wait for the api request to finish.

I have re-written your code to be ES6 compliant.

```
 const Main = () => {

 const [durchläufe, setAlleDurchläufe] = React.useState([]);
 const [lädtDurchläufe, setLädtDurchläufe] = React.useState(false);

 const ladeAlleDurchlauefe = async () => {

   setLädtDurchläufe(true);

   await axios.get(url + "AlleDurchlaeufe").then((resp) => {

     setAlleDurchläufe(resp.data);

      setLädtDurchläufe(false);

  });


}



React.useEffect(() => {
   const init = async () => {
      await ladeAlleDurchlauefe();
   }
init();
}, []);



return (

 <>

  <Container style={{ marginTop: "35px", marginBottom: "25px" }}>

    <Row className="justify-content-center">

    //Here the ELSE statement is called first
      {durchläufe.length > 0 ? (

        durchläufe.map((durchlauf, index) => {

          return (

           <h1>OK</h1>

          );

        })

      ) : (

        <>
      // Render a loading spinner here.
         <h1>Some other Code </h1>
        </>

      )}

    </Row>

  </Container>
 
 </>

  );

}
```

Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: `ladeAlleDurchlauefe` is already an `async` function and doesn't return a value, so what would be the point of awaiting it in the effect? All it does it fetch some data and update state.

Comment: Theres no point in having an async function if you don't await it as you are ignoring the promise.

Comment: Good point, so both `async` functions don't need to be `async`.

Comment: Agreed... I wasn't sure if they were being used else where. However, your comment above is the most valid. With the state being initialised as an empty array when the component mounts it always empty. 
If the OP wants the state never to be empty/loading it should be received in a parent component and parsed as a prop.